# Restore snap-to-grid behaviour for path handles in AI CC 2014

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, grids, cc-2014

one of the new features in AI CC 2014 is path handles ignoring any grid. However, when one wants to construct C2-contious joins between separate objects, precise control over the handle position is needed. I do a lot of icon and sprite art, and there it is imperative that curves from different objects flow exactly the same to create a smooth transition between individual pieces.

How can one restore the ability of handles to snap to the grid like in previous versions of AI?

Comment: personally i wondered about this "feature" is more like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer at the moment is to keep CC installed (or reinstall it if you've uninstalled) and use that where you need to. There is no file format incompatibility between the two versions (that I've come across, anyway), so you can switch back and forth depending on the feature sets you need.